# function setPanel in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs

everyone.

I have an accordion with vanilla javascript and I want to implement with React Hooks. I tried to addapt to jsx but my approach generates a error.

I don't know how rsx adapts the vanilla JavaScript function setPanel.

```
TypeError: panel.setPanel is not a function
HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
Accordion.js:12
   9 | acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  10 |  this.classList.toggle("active");
  11 |  let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
> 12 |  panel.setPanel( this.nextElementSibling);
     | ^  13 |  if (panel.style.display === "block") {
  14 |      panel.style.display = "none";
  15 |  } else {
```

This is my component code:

```
import React, { useEffect} from "react";

export default function Acordeon()
{
    const setStyle= () => {
        let acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++)
        {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                panel.setPanel( this.nextElementSibling);
                if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                    panel.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    panel.style.display = "block";
                }
            });
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        setStyle()
    });

    return({/*HTML Code with some css classes*/}
    )
}
```

The original vanilla JavaScript code:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

In my HTML code have a button with onClick event to display the accordion's content and when is clicked again hides it

Comment: Direct DOM manipulation in React is a ***major*** anti-pattern. React functional components also have no `this` to reference. Are you *actually* rendering a react app into the DOM? In your code what is `panel` that you are trying to invoke `setPanel` of?

Comment: In this case, the page will show this component and the header, footer y navbar components. In my HTML code have a button with the class active that shows the content of a div with class panel, then adds the css style="display: block;"

Comment: How and where is `Acordeon` component being consumed (i.e. rendered)? Can you provide a *running* codesandbox (or similar) that reproduces the issue/error?

Answer (score 0):

with this code solve the problem

```
useEffect(() => {
    let acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function()
        {
            this.classList.toggle("active");

            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.display === "block")
            {
                panel.style.display = "none";
            }

            else
            {
                panel.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
    
}, [])
```